# Como convertir en tipo de datos System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography en C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sqldatatypes

Mi tabla en DB de nombre SqlSpatialType es la siguiente :

```
IDCliente int
Nombre Varchar
GpsLocation Geography
EuclideanaLocation  Geometry
```

Mi formulario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero insertar registros usando EntityFrameworK desde C# , El problema que tengo es como transformar la longitud y latitud ingresada por el cliente... en el tipo de dato correcto

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EMCEntities1 Modelo = new EMCEntities1();
        using (Modelo)
        {
            SqlSpatialType Location = new SqlSpatialType();
            Location.Nombre= txtName.Text;

            // AQUI MI PROBLEMA
            Location .GpsLocation = ? ;
            Location.EuclideanaLocation= ? ;

            Modelo.SqlSpatialType.Add(Location);
            Modelo.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Intenta esta [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23187033/4092887)

Answer (score 1):

Que datos quieres meter en el campo `GpsLocation`?. Lo pregunto porque creo que el tipo que buscas puede ser `GeographyPoint` en vez de `Geography`. Si es asi, `GeographyPoint` tiene un método [Create(Double,Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh918641(v=vs.113).aspx) al que le pasas como parámetros la longitud y la latitud.
De la misma manera, imagino que debes utilizar `GeometryPoint` en vez de `Geometry`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            EMCEntities1 Modelo = new EMCEntities1();
            using (Modelo)
            {
                SqlSpatialType Location = new SqlSpatialType();
                Location.Nombre= txtName.Text;
                string longitud = txtLongitud.Text;
                string latitud = txtLatitud.Text;
                string puntoGeografico = "POINT( " + longitud + " " + latitud + ")";
                Location.GpsLocation =  System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography.FromText(puntoGeografico , 4326);
                Location.EuclideanaLocation = System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeometry.FromText(puntoGeografico , 4326);
                Modelo.SqlSpatialType.Add(Location);
                Modelo.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```